# Running AWS polly with cfexecute

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, aws-cli, amazon-polly, cfexecute

I am trying to use AWS Polly inside of ColdFusion.

This works just fine

```
<cfscript>
cfexecute(
    variable = "standardOutput",
    name = "aws",
    arguments = "polly help",
    timeout = 100
);
</cfscript>

<h3>Results</h3>
<cfoutput><pre>#standardOutput#</pre></cfoutput>
```

This does not apart

```
<cfscript>
cfexecute(
    variable = "standardOutput",
    name = "aws",
    arguments = "polly describe-voices",
    timeout = 100
);
</cfscript>

<h3>Results</h3>
<cfoutput><pre>#standardOutput#</pre></cfoutput>
```

**Thoughts**

I suspect that `cfexecute` is running under different credentials than when I type it in on a command prompt. I wondering if I just need to pass in Amazon Web Services credentials somehow.

Comment: From my brother, who works with both AWS and CF: I believe you will need to pass UN/PW to your service.

Comment: Please elaborate on what happens when you run the second code block.

Comment: One note from our operations folks who do AMZ - Consider using the Java API rather than CF Execute for Polly. Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/polly/AmazonPollyClient.html

Comment: @DanBrucuk : It runs without error, but nothing is loaded into `standardoutput` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things had to be done to fix this.

- I had to go to services and find the account that ColdFusion was running under.
- I then had to go to `c:\users\service` running CF
- Then create a folder called `.aws`
- Create a `credential` file and `config` file.

And then it runs

Note that this was done on Windows 2016